# C# - Multithreaded TCP Server/Client

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I am trying to understand the correct way of how should I make good multithreaded TCP server.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class WorldServer
    {

        public List<ServerClient> clients = new List<ServerClient>();


        public int port = 8080;
        public TcpListener server;
        private bool serverStarted;

        private int connectionIncrementor;

        private MySQLConnection mySQLConnection = new MySQLConnection();
        private MySqlConnection mysqlConn = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorldServer serverInstance = new WorldServer();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting World Server...");

            try
            {
                serverInstance.mysqlConn = new MySqlConnection(serverInstance.mySQLConnection.mysqlConnectionString);
                serverInstance.mysqlConn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to MySQL version: " + serverInstance.mysqlConn.ServerVersion + "\n");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MySQL Error: " + e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (serverInstance.mysqlConn != null)
                {
                    serverInstance.mysqlConn.Close();
                }
            }

            serverInstance.clients = new List<ServerClient>();

            try
            {
                serverInstance.server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, serverInstance.port);
                serverInstance.server.Start();

                serverInstance.StartListening();

                serverInstance.serverStarted = true;

                Console.WriteLine("Server has been started on port: " + serverInstance.port);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket error: " + e.Message);
            }

            while (true)
            {
                serverInstance.Update();
            }

        }


        private void Update()
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Call");
            if (!serverStarted)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (ServerClient c in clients.ToList())
            {
                //Check if TCP is not null
                if (c.tcp == null)
                    return;

                // Is the client still connected?
                if (!IsConnected(c.tcp))
                {
                    c.tcp.Close();
                    clients.Remove(c);
                    Console.WriteLine(c.connectionId + " has disconnected.");
                    continue;
                    //Console.WriteLine("Check for connection?\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Check for message from Client.
                    NetworkStream s = c.tcp.GetStream();
                    if (s.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        string data = c.streamReader.ReadLine();

                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            if (ValidateJSON(data))
                            {
                                Thread incomingData = new Thread(() => OnIncomingData(c, data));
                                incomingData.Start();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    //continue;
                }
            }



        }

        public bool ValidateJSON(string s)
        {
            try
            {
                JToken.Parse(s);
                return true;
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void OnIncomingData(ServerClient c, string data)
        {
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

            string header = json.header;
            //Console.WriteLine("HEADER ID:" + json.header);

            string connId = json.connectionId;
            int.TryParse(connId, out int connectionId);

            int characterId = 0;
            Dictionary<string, string> receivedData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            if (json.data != null)
            {
                receivedData = json.data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            }


            if (json.data["characterId"] != null)
            {
                characterId = json.data["characterId"];
            }

            string prefix = header.Substring(0, 2);
            if (prefix != "1x")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown packet: " + data + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                string HeaderPacket = header.Substring(2);
                switch (HeaderPacket)
                {
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unknown packet: " + data + "\n");
                        break;
                    case "004":
                        Console.WriteLine("Test Packet"); ;
                        break;
                }
            }


            //Broadcast(null, data, clients);
            //Console.WriteLine(c.clientName + " has sent the following message :" + data);
        }


        public bool IsConnected(TcpClient c)
        {
            try
            {
                if (c != null && c.Client != null && c.Client.Connected)
                {
                    if (c.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                    {
                        return !(c.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.Peek) == 0);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void StartListening()
        {
            server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnConnection, server);
        }

        private void OnConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            connectionIncrementor++;
            TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
            clients.Add(new ServerClient(listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)));
            clients[clients.Count - 1].connectionId = connectionIncrementor;
            StartListening();


            //Send a message to everyone, say someone has connected!
            Dictionary<string, object> SendDataBroadcast = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            SendDataBroadcast.Add("connectionId", clients[clients.Count - 1].connectionId);

            Broadcast("001", SendDataBroadcast, clients[clients.Count - 1].connectionId);
            Console.WriteLine(clients[clients.Count - 1].connectionId + " has connected.");
        }

        public void Broadcast(string header, Dictionary<string, object> data, int cnnId = 0)
        {
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);

            foreach (ServerClient c in clients)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (header == null)
                    {
                        header = "000";
                    }
                    JsonData SendData = new JsonData();
                    SendData.header = "0x" + header;
                    SendData.data = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
                    SendData.connectionId = cnnId;
                    string JSonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SendData);
                    //Console.WriteLine("SENDING: " + JSonData);
                    c.streamWriter.WriteLine(JSonData);
                    c.streamWriter.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Write error : " + e.Message + " to client " + c.connectionId);
                }
            }
        }


        public void Send(string header, Dictionary<string, object> data, int cnnId)
        {
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);

            foreach (ServerClient c in clients.ToList())
            {

                if (c.connectionId == cnnId)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Sending...");
                        if (header == null)
                        {
                            header = "000";
                        }
                        JsonData SendData = new JsonData();
                        SendData.header = "0x" + header;
                        SendData.data = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
                        SendData.connectionId = cnnId;

                        string JSonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SendData);

                        c.streamWriter.WriteLine(JSonData);
                        c.streamWriter.Flush();
                        //Console.WriteLine("Trying to send data to connection id: " + cnnId + " data:" + sendData);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Write error : " + e.Message + " to client " + c.connectionId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ServerClient
    {
        public TcpClient tcp;
        public StreamReader streamReader;
        public StreamWriter streamWriter;
        public int accountId;
        public int connectionId;
        public ServerClient(TcpClient clientSocket)
        {
            tcp = clientSocket;
            streamReader = new StreamReader(tcp.GetStream(), false);
            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tcp.GetStream());
            clientSocket.NoDelay = true;
        }
    }
```

The TCP server works. However I am really not sure if this is the best approach I can take.

1. Have I made the multi-threading well ? Probably not. I would like to receive advices where i can make it better.
2. Do I need to create a new thread on every `OnIncomingData` ?
3. Do I need to create new thread on every `Send` and `Broadcast` ?
4. Very often I receive error here `foreach (ServerClient c in clients.ToList())`. What can be the cause of it ?
5. What parts of the client is good to be multithreaded also aka the listening function for incoming data or the sending functions?
6. All advices are most welcome!

Comment: Sounds more that you would like to have a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) rather than having a problem which you can't solve?

Comment: You do NOT want to create a new thread on each incomming data. If you want to handle subsequent messages concurrently, handle them on the threadpool else put them on a queue and handle them with one thread.

Comment: To my TCP system I'm using BeginReceive/EndReceive, BeginSend/BeginEnd which are a callback when some data has incoming. Same for BeginConnect/EndConnect and BeginAccept/EndAccept. The functions Receive are on a single recursive Thread.

Comment: Start thinking at a higher level. Use async features to basically say "I want this to happen, make sure I get back control when it has happened and I've got work to do" and ignore the specific mechanisms by which this is achieved. Often, this will be able to relieve you *completely* from thinking about e.g. threads. Why would you want to manually plumb such code together in this day and age?

Comment: I have no experience with threadpool. Also why it is good practice to create new thread on new client connection? Should i access that thread and run what had to run inside it ?

Answer (score -3):

I wrote code for an OP last year that was a TCP Server and wrote to a SQL Server.  I modified that code a few minutes ago to make it more general.  The changes are not tested but original code worked very well.  I used Asynchronous Send and Receive.  I also used a fifo to send messages from the transport layer to the application layer.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

namespace TCP_Server
{
    public class StateObject
    {
        public long connectionNumber = -1;
        public Socket workSocket { get; set; }
        public byte[] buffer { get; set; }
        public int fifoCount { get; set; }

    }
    public enum PROCESS_STATE
    {
        ACCEPT,
        READ,
        PROCESS,
        UNPACK
    }
    public enum UNPACK_STATUS
    {
        ERROR,
        NOT_ENOUGH_BYTES,
        BAD_CRC,
        GOOD_MESSAGE,
        DEFAULT
    }
    public enum PROTOCOL_NUMBER
    {
        LOGIN_MESSAGE,
        NONE
    }


    class Program
    {
        const string IP = "127.0.0.1";
        const int PORT = 8841;
        const Boolean test = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Server server = new Server(IP, PORT, test);

            Console.WriteLine("Connection Ended");

        }
    }

    public class Server
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        const string CONNECT_STRING = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDataTable;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        const string LOGIN_INSERT_COMMMAND_TEXT = "use MyTable INSERT INTO Login (TerminalID,Date) VALUES(@TerminalID,@Date)";
        const string LOCATION_INSERT_COMMMAND_TEXT = "INSERT INTO MyTable (CurrTime, Message)" +
            "VALUES (@CurrTime, @Message)";
        static SqlConnection conn = null;
        static SqlCommand cmdLogin = null;
        static SqlCommand cmdLocation = null;

        static long connectionNumber = 0;
        //mapping of connection number to StateObject
        static Dictionary<long, KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>> connectionDict = new Dictionary<long, KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>>();
        //fifo contains list of connections number wait with receive data
        public static List<long> fifo = new List<long>();

        public static AutoResetEvent allDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        public static AutoResetEvent acceptDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);




        public enum DATABASE_MESSAGE_TYPE
        {
            LOGIN,
            LOCATION
        }
        public class WriteDBMessage
        {
            public DATABASE_MESSAGE_TYPE message { get; set; }
        }
        public class WriteDBMessageLogin : WriteDBMessage
        {
            public DateTime date { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }
        }
        public class WriteDBMessageLocation : WriteDBMessage
        {
            public DateTime currTime { get; set; }
            public byte[] message { get; set; }
        }
        public static class WriteDBAsync
        {
            public enum Mode
            {
                READ,
                WRITE
            }
            public static List<WriteDBMessage> fifo = new List<WriteDBMessage>();
            public static System.Timers.Timer timer = null;

            public static void WriteDatabase()
            {
                timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
                timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
                timer.Start();
            }
            public static WriteDBMessage ReadWriteFifo(Mode mode, WriteDBMessage message)
            {
                Object thisLock2 = new Object();

                lock (thisLock2)
                {
                    switch (mode)
                    {
                        case Mode.READ:
                            if (fifo.Count > 0)
                            {
                                message = fifo[0];
                                fifo.RemoveAt(0);
                            }
                            break;
                        case Mode.WRITE:
                            fifo.Add(message);
                            break;
                    }

                }
                return message;
            }
            static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                timer.Enabled = false;
                WriteDBMessage row = null;
                int rowsAdded = 0;
                uint number = 0;
                try
                {

                    while ((row = ReadWriteFifo(Mode.READ, null)) != null)
                    {
                        switch (row.message)
                        {
                            case DATABASE_MESSAGE_TYPE.LOGIN:
                                 cmdLogin.Parameters["@Date"].Value = ((WriteDBMessageLogin)row).date;
                                rowsAdded = cmdLogin.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Error : '{0}'", ex.Message);
                }
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }


        public Server(string IP, int port, Boolean test)
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECT_STRING);
                conn.Open();

                cmdLogin = new SqlCommand(LOGIN_INSERT_COMMMAND_TEXT, conn);
                cmdLogin.Parameters.Add("@TerminalID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8);
                cmdLogin.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);

                cmdLocation = new SqlCommand(LOCATION_INSERT_COMMMAND_TEXT, conn);
                cmdLocation.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmdLocation.Parameters.Add("@TrackTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmdLocation.Parameters.Add("@currTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmdLocation.Parameters.Add("@Longitude", SqlDbType.NChar, 50);
                cmdLocation.Parameters.Add("@Lattitude", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmdLocation.Parameters.Add("@speed", SqlDbType.Float);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : '{0}'", ex.Message);
                //Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                //initialize the timer for writing to database.
                WriteDBAsync.WriteDatabase();
                StartListening(IP, port, test);

                // Open 2nd listener to simulate two devices, Only for testing
                //StartListening(IP, port + 1, test);

                ProcessMessages();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : '{0}'", ex.Message);
                //Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
        }

        public void StartListening(string IP, int port, Boolean test)
        {
            try
            {
                // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
                // The DNS name of the computer
                // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(IP);  //Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                //IPAddress local = IPAddress.Parse(IP);

                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = null;
                if (test)
                {
                    localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
                }
                else
                {
                    localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
                }

                // Create a TCP/IP socket.
                Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.


                allDone.Reset();
                acceptDone.Reset();
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);

                //login code, wait for 1st message
                Console.WriteLine("Wait 5 seconds for login message");

                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        public void ProcessMessages()
        {
            UInt16 sendCRC = 0;
            DateTime date;
            int year = 0;
            int month = 0;
            int day = 0;
            int hour = 0;
            int minute = 0;
            int second = 0;

            KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject> byteState;
            KeyValuePair<UNPACK_STATUS, byte[]> status;
            byte[] receiveMessage = null;
            StateObject state = null;
            byte[] serialNumber = null;
            byte[] serverFlagBit = null;
            byte[] stringArray = null;
            string stringMessage = "";
            byte lengthOfCommand = 0;

            PROTOCOL_NUMBER protocolNumber = PROTOCOL_NUMBER.NONE;            

            try
            {
                Boolean firstMessage = true;
                acceptDone.Set();
                //loop forever
                while (true)
                {
                    allDone.WaitOne();

                    //read fifo until empty
                    while (true)
                    {
                        //read one connection until buffer doesn't contain any more packets
                        byteState = ReadWrite(PROCESS_STATE.PROCESS, null, null, -1);

                        if (byteState.Value.fifoCount == -1) break;

                        state = byteState.Value;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            status = Unpack(byteState);
                            if (status.Key == UNPACK_STATUS.NOT_ENOUGH_BYTES)
                                break;

                            if (status.Key == UNPACK_STATUS.ERROR)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Error : Bad Receive Message, Data");
                                break;
                            }

                            //message is 2 start bytes + 1 byte (message length) + 1 byte message length + 2 end bytes
                            receiveMessage = status.Value;

                            int messageLength = receiveMessage[2];
                            Console.WriteLine("Status : '{0}', Receive Message : '{1}'", status.Key == UNPACK_STATUS.GOOD_MESSAGE ? "Good" : "Bad", BytesToString(receiveMessage.Take(messageLength + 5).ToArray()));

                            if (status.Key != UNPACK_STATUS.GOOD_MESSAGE)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (firstMessage)
                                {
                                    if (receiveMessage[3] != 0x01)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Error : Expected Login Message : '{0}'", BytesToString(receiveMessage));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    firstMessage = false;
                                }

                                //skip start bytes, message length.  then go back 4 bytes (CRC and serial number)
                                serialNumber = receiveMessage.Skip(2 + 1 + messageLength - 4).Take(2).ToArray();

                                protocolNumber = (PROTOCOL_NUMBER)receiveMessage[3];
                                Console.WriteLine("Protocol Number : '{0}'", protocolNumber.ToString());
                                switch (protocolNumber)
                                {
                                    case PROTOCOL_NUMBER.LOGIN_MESSAGE:
                                         break;

                                } //end switch
                            }// End if
                        } //end while
                    }//end while fifo > 0
                    allDone.Reset();
                }//end while true
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
        static string BytesToString(byte[] bytes)
        {

            return string.Join("", bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
        }
        static KeyValuePair<UNPACK_STATUS, byte[]> Unpack(KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject> bitState)
        {
            List<byte> working_buffer = bitState.Key;
            //return null indicates an error
            if (working_buffer.Count() < 3) return new KeyValuePair<UNPACK_STATUS, byte[]>(UNPACK_STATUS.NOT_ENOUGH_BYTES, null);

            int len = working_buffer[2];

            if (working_buffer.Count < len + 5) return new KeyValuePair<UNPACK_STATUS, byte[]>(UNPACK_STATUS.NOT_ENOUGH_BYTES, null);
            // check start and end bytes
            // remove message fro workig buffer and dictionary 
            KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject> byteState = ReadWrite(PROCESS_STATE.UNPACK, null, null, bitState.Value.connectionNumber);
            if (byteState.Key.Count == 0) return new KeyValuePair<UNPACK_STATUS, byte[]>(UNPACK_STATUS.ERROR, null);

            List<byte> packet = byteState.Key;

            //crc test
            byte[] crc = packet.Skip(len + 1).Take(2).ToArray();
            ushort crcShort = (ushort)((crc[0] << 8) | crc[1]);
            //skip start bytes, crc, and end bytes

            return new KeyValuePair<UNPACK_STATUS, byte[]>(UNPACK_STATUS.GOOD_MESSAGE, packet.ToArray());
        }

        static KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject> ReadWrite(PROCESS_STATE ps, Socket handler, IAsyncResult ar, long unpackConnectionNumber)
        {
            KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject> byteState = new KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>(); ;
            StateObject stateObject = null;
            int bytesRead = -1;
            int workingBufferLen = 0;
            List<byte> working_buffer = null;
            byte[] buffer = null;

            Object thisLock1 = new Object();

            lock (thisLock1)
            {
                switch (ps)
                {
                    case PROCESS_STATE.ACCEPT:

                        acceptDone.WaitOne();
                        acceptDone.Reset();
                        stateObject = new StateObject();
                        stateObject.buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        connectionDict.Add(connectionNumber, new KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>(new List<byte>(), stateObject));
                        stateObject.connectionNumber = connectionNumber++;

                        stateObject.workSocket = handler;

                        byteState = new KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>(null, stateObject);
                        acceptDone.Set();
                        break;

                    case PROCESS_STATE.READ:
                        //catch when client disconnects

                        //wait if accept is being called
                        //acceptDone.WaitOne();
                        try
                        {
                            stateObject = ar.AsyncState as StateObject;
                            // Read data from the client socket. 
                            bytesRead = stateObject.workSocket.EndReceive(ar);

                            if (bytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                byteState = connectionDict[stateObject.connectionNumber];

                                buffer = new byte[bytesRead];
                                Array.Copy(byteState.Value.buffer, buffer, bytesRead);

                                byteState.Key.AddRange(buffer);
                            }
                            //only put one instance of connection number into fifo
                            if (!fifo.Contains(byteState.Value.connectionNumber))
                            {

                                fifo.Add(byteState.Value.connectionNumber);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //will get here if client disconnects
                            fifo.RemoveAll(x => x == byteState.Value.connectionNumber);
                            connectionDict.Remove(byteState.Value.connectionNumber);
                            byteState = new KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>(new List<byte>(), null);
                        }
                        break;

                    case PROCESS_STATE.PROCESS:
                        if (fifo.Count > 0)
                        {
                            //get message from working buffer
                            //unpack will later delete message
                            //remove connection number from fifo
                            // the list in the key in known as the working buffer
                            byteState = new KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>(connectionDict[fifo[0]].Key, connectionDict[fifo[0]].Value);
                            fifo.RemoveAt(0);
                            //put a valid value in fifoCount so -1 below can be detected.
                            byteState.Value.fifoCount = fifo.Count;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //getting here is normal when there is no more work to be performed
                            //set fifocount to zero so rest of code know fifo was empty so code waits for next receive message
                            byteState = new KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>(null, new StateObject() { fifoCount = -1 });
                        }
                        break;

                    case PROCESS_STATE.UNPACK:
                        try
                        {
                            working_buffer = connectionDict[unpackConnectionNumber].Key;
                            workingBufferLen = working_buffer[2];
                            if ((working_buffer[0] != 0x78) && (working_buffer[1] != 0x78) && (working_buffer[workingBufferLen + 3] != 0x0D) && (working_buffer[workingBufferLen + 4] != 0x0A))
                            {



                                working_buffer.Clear();
                                return new KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>(new List<byte>(), null);
                            }
                            List<byte> packet = working_buffer.GetRange(0, workingBufferLen + 5);
                            working_buffer.RemoveRange(0, workingBufferLen + 5);
                            byteState = new KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject>(packet, null);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            int testPoint = 0;
                        }

                        break;
                }// end switch
            }

            return byteState;
        }

        public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {

                // Get the socket that handles the client request.
                // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
                // from the asynchronous state object.

                Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

                // Create the state object.
                StateObject state = ReadWrite(PROCESS_STATE.ACCEPT, handler, ar, -1).Value;

                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                int myerror = -1;
            }
        }
        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = ar.AsyncState as StateObject;
                Socket handler = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the client socket. 
                KeyValuePair<List<byte>, StateObject> byteState = ReadWrite(PROCESS_STATE.READ, handler, ar, -1);

                if (byteState.Value != null)
                {
                    allDone.Set();
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    int testPoint = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                int myerror = -1;
            }

            // Signal the main thread to continue.  
            allDone.Set();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overlow is not CodeProject or any other code snippet sharing website. Answers ought to answer the OP's question(s), not be "use this code instead" code dumps.